# Proyecto publicado con asp.net core 2.2 da error Development Mode ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buenas tardes este es el error que me genera luego de haber publicado mi proyecto asp.net core 2.2.

Exactamente el error aparece cuando me registro. pues allí debería pedirme que revise el correo y que confirme desde allí pero no pasa eso.

Comment: Cuando hiciste el deployment, ¿tenías habilitado el entorno de producción o de desarrollo?

Comment: Por otro lado, ¿en qué sistema operativo hiciste el deploy?

Comment: desconosco el tema de entorno de produccion y desarrollo por que no creo que lo aiga activado , el deply lo ise en windows

Comment: Mejoras gramaticales: desconozco, producción, haya en lugar de aiga, deploy en lugar de deply, hice en lugar de ise. Ahora, en las propiedades de tu proyecto, ve a "Debug" y mira las variables de entorno que tienes, ahí hay una by default con "name" = "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" y "value" = "Development"